# Error in including header file in .h file but not in .cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, header-files, include-path

With Visual Studio 2013 I'm writing a Dynamic Library and I need to use some third-party libraries. Each library comes in the form of header .h, a .dll and .lib files. I added the library's directory to my project, I changed the "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories" to include the header file and I added the .lib file to the Additional Dependencies of the Linker.

If I try to include the header .h in my .cpp file using

```
    #include "library.h"
```

everything works fine and the compiler it gives no error. But if I put this line in my header .h file and try to compile I get this error:

> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'library.h': No such file or directory

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say **to include the header file**.  But you need to include the header file **directory**.

Comment: Is the project that contains the Header File you're trying to include the .h into the same one as the .cpp File?  #include "library.h" uses Relative Directory Paths, not absolute ones.

Comment: `#include <library.h>` should work since you added the path.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. In "Additional include Directories" I added the directory containing the header file. The .h and the .cpp files are in the same directory and in the same project.

Comment: Done! There was an error in the include path. Thanks everyone!